# Python - How do I append numbers inside the list and

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, append

Whenever I try appending numbers from my input to my list, it goes outside one of the brackets instead of inside the two brackets

Is there a way to only have one pair of brackets instead of two?

Also I am trying to add random numbers between 1-3 and i get,

```
[[2, 1, 3]]
```

How can you create random numbers in the tenths decimal place

My Code,

```
import random
array = []

nums = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)
array.append(nums)
print(array)

for x in range(2):
    nums = int(input("what are your numbers "))
    array.append(nums)
    print(array)
```

I get,

```
[[2, 1, 3]]
what are your numbers 3
[[2, 1, 3], 3]
what are your numbers 2
[[2, 1, 3], 3, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Do you mean `array = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)`?

Comment: Use `array.extend`

Comment: I'm quite impressed that nobody mentioned `extend` before. Thanks @ruaridhw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

random.sample() is already returning list as return value to you so there is no need to append it to another one

```
array = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)
```

In your code

```
import random

array = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)

print(array)

for x in range(2):
    number = int(input("what are your numbers "))
    array.append(number)
    print(array)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can make the random number have a tenths place?

Answer (score 0):

You first let the nums be a list `nums = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)`.
Thus if you append **nums** to **array**.So the **array** becomes a list that contains other lists instead of integer.

May be you could just simply try `array = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)`.It will let **array** to be a list of integer,then append other numbers you need.:D

There is actually another way to do what you want,just `array += random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)`it will make the content in **random.sample** appended into the array instead of being append as a list.